# Placing a window in WIN CE

Tags: windows, mfc, windows-ce

How do we specify the placement position of a window using MFC in Win CE? It does not support the WINDOWPLACEMENT class that is available in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CreateWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms960010.aspx) seems to have a `x` and `y` coordinates to position the window.

Update:
Also if you look at the code of the resource file `rc` you will see:

```
MYDIALOG_DIALOG DIALOG  0, 0, 182, 97
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW | 0x80000000L
CAPTION "mycaption"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg"
BEGIN
    CONTROL         132,IDC_STATIC,"Static",SS_BITMAP,7,7,20,18
    LTEXT           "blah blah",IDC_STATIC,32,11,133,12
    CONTROL         "some control",IDC_DEVICE_BTN,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,58,33,64,10
    CONTROL         "control",IDC_HOST_BTN,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,58,49,57,10
    PUSHBUTTON      "control",IDC_BUTTON1,64,73,47,17
END
```

Notice the `MYDIALOG_DIALOG DIALOG  0, 0, 182, 97` first 0, 0 - that is the window positioning.